# How can I block internet access to certain Wireguard clients?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, android, wireguard

I have a working Wireguard setup, and multiple devices connect to it. I also set it up such that all the clients route their network/internet activity through the Wireguard server via "0.0.0.0/0, ::/0'

I am going to add couple new devices to this setup, however I want these new devices to be able to access the lan but have no access to the Internet. What I want is to be able to route all traffic through the WG server but make server deny non LAN connections, rendering those devices without any meaningful way to make Internet connections.

I can set up a DNS server to deny domain look ups but that is really not enough to block the actual packets.

I have my WG server running on Debian and my client devcies are Androids and Windows machines.

Edit:
I used the recommended calculator and all I am getting is an empty **AllowedIPs** list

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

##### AllowedIPs

Pro Custodibus has a [Wireguard AllowedIPs Calculator](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/03/wireguard-allowedips-calculator/) which you can use to customize your  WireGuard config.

Additionally there are some notes on that page about alternative approaches such as routing.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit please.

Comment: @yaruncan  that should be a `comment` on my answer, not an `edit` to your question.

Comment: If you `disallow` all possible IPs, it makes sense that you are left with `""` (no IPs).

Comment: AllowedIPs on the server side only limits sources that the clients may send from, not the destinations, so it won't really work here. AllowedIPs on the clients would work (if applied to the server section) but is easily bypassable by the client.

Comment: @user1686 that seemed to fit the bill.  He wants to deny some LAN clients VPN access so it is source IP based.  The security is what it is and subject to the same IP based issues as any other IP based filtering solution.  Reminder he gives these devices LAN access but is worried about outgoing (WAN) traffic through wireguard. Thought it was a simple solution for someone with limited knowledge.

Comment: I am using Debian Testing and I cant put multiple IPs in the AllowedIPs, WG service fails to start if I have a line like "AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.12/32, 192.168.1.0/24" So this solution wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Packet filtering is done using a **firewall**. Debian has two – **iptables** (with various wrappers, such as Ferm) and **nftables** (aka nft). Both of which allow you to literally block packets sent not to a local address; for example:

```
chain forward {
    iifname "wg0" jump {
        ip daddr 192.168.1.0/24 accept
        ip6 daddr fd1b:2c4d:7f8e::/48 accept
        reject
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does this exactly do?

Comment: It configures the Linux nftables firewall to block packets sent to a not local address.

Comment: Ok. And damn. You answered within minutes 